# CSS: Put two buttons bootstrap side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code looks like here:

```
<td>
   <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
   <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"style="float:left;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
   </form>
</td>
```

Now buttons looks like this:

[image]

Which rules of CSS I have to put to fix it?

Comment: Is [this](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/) usefull?

Comment: Usually yes, but in this case no. I'm 99% sure it's cause button it's inside a form..

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty hard to help you only with your little code, but here are some solution that could help

**With flexbox :**

```
    <td style="display: flex;">
       <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
       <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
       </form>
    </td>
```

**With display inline-block :**

```
<td>
   <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="display: inline-block;">View</a>
   <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
   </form>
</td>
```

**With bootstrap columns :**

```
<td>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your form an inline-block. There are helper classes in 
Bootstrap for that: `class="visible-*-inline-block"`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<td>
   <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm d-inline-block">View</a>
   <form class="visible-xs-inline-block" method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
        <!--{{method_field('DELETE')}}-->
   </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to fix it, put code like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
  <td>
     <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
     <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
     {{method_field('DELETE')}}
  </td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  body {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <td>
       <a href="{{ route('admin.admins.show', $admin->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>
       <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"style="float:left;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
       </form>
    </td>
  </body>
</html>
```